# How to make installer for Eclipse RCP

Tags: installation, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I would like to create installer for Eclipse RCP application. What is the best way to do this?
It is possible?

Eclipse Platform Version: 3.6.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a plug-in project, create a product configuration.

Configure it. On the Dependencies tab, the *"Add required plug-ins"* button is your friend.

Build the product -- e.g., through the *"Exporting"* section on the Overview tab.

Once it's built, you can build an installer with a third-party install tool compatible with the target operating system/s.

More detail is provided in the Eclipse FAQ under ["How do I create an Eclipse product?"](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_create_an_Eclipse_product%3F)

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions that I know should make the job of creating an installer easy:

1. [EclipseNSIS](http://eclipsensis.sourceforge.net/index.shtml) - which is **windows-only**
2. Use [Pulse OneInstall](http://www.poweredbypulse.com/oneinstall.php) - which seems to be cross-platform.

I have not used either of the above, but have been researching them as well. Both should have wizards that guide your through the above.